# NodeJS - Wait for return inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, return, settimeout

I am trying to learn async/await. I want to wait for the return statement inside my async function. I have to call it several times so I used a setTiemout inside.

EDIT:

```
//Processing gallery
async function somefunction(){
    async function getPictureR(){

        /* some code */

        if($('.actions > .prev', html)[0]){
            older = $('.actions > .prev', html)[0].attribs.href;
        } else {
            console.log('return');
            return;
        }

        /* some code */

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(getPictureR, 1 * 1000/2);    
        })
    }
    await getPictureR();
    console.log('getPictureR done');
}
```

I've tried `await getPictureR()` but it triggers right after the first call to the function. How can I wait for that return ?

Comment: You need to promisify `setTimeout`. Then you can just `await` it in a loop.

Comment: Could you elaborate please ? I've just read the nodejs documntation but I don't get it. The example executes the code after the first setTimeout call

Comment: Nevermind I got it, many thanks ! I'll post my solution

Comment: @Bergi Looks like I've commented a bit fast. Can you still help ?

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show what you tried? Maybe you were on the right path.

Comment: just did. I thought this would work, but now the code after `getPictureR()` isn't executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never call a promise-returning function, like `getPictureR`, from an asynchronous (non-promise) callback or [inside the `new Promise` constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it). You also were never resolving the `new Promise`. You are looking for

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1 * 1000/2);    
}).then(() => {
    return getPictureR(); // do the promise call in a `then` callback to properly chain it
})
```

---

But since you're using `async`/`await`, you don't need the recursive function and the `then` chaining anyway. Also you can factor out the `setTimeout`-in-promise wrapping in a separate helper function:

```
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
}
async function somefunction() {
    while (true)
        /* some code */

        const prev = $('.actions > .prev', html);
        if (prev.length) {
            older = prev[0].attribs.href;
        } else {
            console.log('return');
            break;
        }

        /* some code */

        await delay(1 * 1000/2);
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
    console.log('getPicture done');
}
```

Comment: Good job @Bergi!

Comment: This works like a charm ! I would have never thought of using a `while` loop,  Thanks again !